# How to query ADO.Net C# Connection Properties

Tags: c#, ado.net

I need to test connecting to an ADO.Net provider in a number of different ways to ensure that the correct connection settings are being set. Is there anyway to query the DBConnection object to ask what the user name of the authenticated user is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that no generic approach within `DbConnection` or `IDbConnection` is powerful enough to achieve this. The closest thing that I can think is by reading the [ConnectionString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.connectionstring.aspx) property and parsing it to get the username. For the parsing, you can utilize the [DbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.connectionstring.aspx), which is similar to a Dictionary, then you can get the value of spesific key (e.g. "User ID", "user", "uid"). Beware that some dbms using a totally different key for defining user in connection-string.

If you allowed to use dbms spesific class directly, for MS-SQL, you can parse the connection-string using [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.aspx). Another specific approach is using [SqlConnection.Credential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.credential.aspx) that has [UserId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential.userid.aspx) property.

Comment: I don't think a SqlConnection would work since I'm not connecting to MS-SQL. Also, the user name that I'm looking for shouldn't be in the connection string since I'm using integrated security (or at least trying to). Part of the idea is to verify which user gets logged in if I pass both username and password and also set integrated security to true.

Comment: For integrated security, I think the only option left is to deeply looking into the specific function/API that your database use (e.g. SYS_CONTEXT for oracle).

Answer (score 0):

The following example returns the name of the current user.

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a way to query that information through my C# test application. Perhaps a better solution would be to create a DbCommand object and then set this as the query text?

Comment: This also won't work for databases which don't have special tables or logic to support that feature.